# jQuery .append javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, partial-views

snip of html

```
<div id="list">
    <div id="item">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/items.js?id=@item.Id&time=today"></script>
     </div>
</div>
```

when user scroll down I add more items (`div id="item"`) to `div "list"`. I get more items using

```
$.get("/test/items/",
     function (data) {
        if (data != '') {
            $('#list').append(data);
        }
     }
)
```

returned data contains javascript and looks like this.

```
<div id="item">
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/items.js?id=@item.Id&time=today"></script>
</div>
```

but after doing append I dont see javascript did anything. in original html as mentioned before works fine.

Comment: list is id... but ur selector takes it as a class.. is this a typo ' $('.list').append(data);' ????

Comment: yea it was typo :) thank

Answer (score 2):

Try This one

```
$.get("/test/items/",
     function (data) {
        if (data != '') {
            $('#list').append(data);
         }
```

Comment: Even if the op were to add the script this way, would it still execute on append? This is for my curiosity

Comment: @ryadavilli What do you mean? This should append `data` to `#list`.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, In the original post, it was mentioned that "but after doing append I dont see javascript did anything". I assumed this meant, that after the script got appended, the OP expected the newly added script to execute and perform some action. In the first example, the OP has a <script> tag, which would include the script and execute. I wanted to know, if appending the script would also have the same effect.

Comment: @ryadavilli please read "but after doing append" as "but after having attempted append" ;-) . The `.list` most likely didn't select anything.

Comment: it was typo (my question still holds :). @ryadavilli - you understood question correct) . It should be $('#list').append(data); instead of $('.list').append(data);

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You're making a request to get `HTML`, and in that html is a script reference. Are you trying to load a script?

If so, you should have your server return simply the *url*, not the entire HTML. You can then use jQuery to get a script and execute it.

```
// This GET should return, "http://localhost/items.js?id=@item.Id&time=today"
$.get("/test/items/",
  function (data) {
    $.getScript(data);
  }
```

The `getScript()` function is just shorthand for an AJAX call, and you can supply callbacks for success, failure etc.

Comment: Even if the op were to add the script this way, would it still execute on append? This is for my curiosity

Comment: @user1715729 - Oh ok.. Well I changed my answer. I don't know if it helps but it's completely different now that I know it was a typo.